# What is the most intelligent way to approach calculation of computing capacity for running a program?

Tags: database, perl, memory-management, computer-science, distributed-computing

I need insight on how one would go about estimating the computing power he might need to run a program and projecting into the future when the project expands.

Comment: http://shimmie.shishnet.org/v2/post/view/2221

Comment: clever... I am looking for something more scientific...

Comment: mobule's suggestion is, unfortunately, the standard practice in most software development these days.

Answer (score 0):

Put another way, "How well will my application scale?"

1) Identify the slowest component in the system. Determine what it's complexity is (i.e. O(nlogn) or O(n^2) for example)

2) How big is my data now, at what rate will it grow?

3) Identify whether my application can be broken into separately run components

Comment: I guess I am looking to identify components of a formula that can tell me why identical program runs at different speed on two different machines. I know the speed is ultimately constrained by the laws of physics but what exactly explains the differences I don't know. I think this is the essence of my question.

Comment: @seaworthy: if that's the case, then I suggest you re-word your question.